# Android setvisibility nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, visibility, layout-inflater

I have a RelativeLayout in my main.xml, which is initially invisible(visibility=gone). Later in a class in the main fragment, in an onClick event, I want to set it to visible.:

```
RelativeLayout results = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.result_bar);
results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);------->>>>**NullPointerException**
```

Why am I getting this Null Pointer exception? How can I set it to visible? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're trying to access a layout from your activity in your fragment's code. Is that right?

Comment: OK, you can't do that directly. You should define an event in your fragment and listen to it in the activity. Then hide the layout from your activity.

Comment: And where should I define RelativeLayout results = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.result_bar); ?

Comment: I call it now with an interface from the class: mCallback.makeResultsbarVisible(); but get again a NPE. Why?

Comment: MainActivity: @Override
 public void makeResultsbarVisible()
 {
  RelativeLayout results = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.result_bar);
  results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }